# rsyslog is still sending messages to omusrmsg even after using `stop` command

Tags: ubuntu, rsyslog

I have the following lines in the `50-default.conf` file (in `/etc/rsyslog.d`):

```
local0.emerg       stop
*.emerg            :omusrmsg:*
```

But all `local0` messages are still being sent to every user logged on the system.  I can't seem to find any filter that will tell rsyslog to stop sending those `local0` messages to `omusrmsg`.

I have confirmed that the log msgs really are using `local0` (they are also being written to a log file, which writes the facility value also).  I have also confirmed that `:omusrmsg:` is not used on any other line in the rsyslog config, unless there is a config file hiding somewhere (the only config files I see are `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and 4 files in the `/etc/rsyslog.d` directory, and 2 of those 4 files are mine).

I have also tried these entries in that conf file, before the `:omusrmsg:` line:

```
local0.*     stop
if ( ( $syslogseverity <= '0' ) and ( $syslogfacility-text == 'local0' ) ) then stop
if ( ( $syslogseverity <= '0' ) and ( $syslogfacility == '16' ) ) then stop
if ( ( $syslogseverity == '0' ) and ( $syslogfacility == '16' ) ) then stop
```

I have restarted rsyslogd (via `sudo service rsyslog restart`) many times.  And I have made other changes to the rsyslog config that work fine.  Other than this, all logging seems to work fine.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Any help would be much appreciated.

I am running `rsyslogd 8.16.0` on `Ubuntu 16.04`.